# How to use the Neo4J Cypher Query Builder?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-builder

I have a below Cypher

```
match (p:Person)-[]->(s:FamilyStatus) where s.FamilyStatus = "MiddleClass" return p ,(p)-[:RESIDES_ON]-(:Person) limit 1
```

how can this above Cypher query can be write with the Neo4j Cypher query builder?

If Neo4J provide any Java based Cypher query builder?

My requirement is user will provide me the all the details through the restapi and i have to make the cypher query with provided details and execute it and return the response.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4J currently doesn't support any Query Builder in Java. But there are a javascript library [there](https://github.com/jamesfer/cypher-query-builder).

But you can do it by yourself if your queries do not very complex and unpredictable use String Builder.